# Why is this true $v \in H_2(\Omega) \Rightarrow v \in C(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

As the title say, I'm trying to figure out why is the following true:
$$v \in H_2(\Omega) \Rightarrow v \in C(\Omega)$$
with
$H_2(\Omega) = \{f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}: \|f^{(k)}\|_{L_2} < \infty, \forall 0 \leq k \leq 2\}$ (say $\Omega = [0,1]$).
I may have missed something in the statement but I think the idea is here. Google wasn't very helpful :'(

We use that to show that the solution of elliptic PDE's (which are in $H_2$ if the right-hand side is in $L_2$) are continuous.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Look the PDE Evans book, chapter 6. Maybe help you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#General_Sobolev_inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the Sobolev embedding theorem. Perhaps view the bottom of page 160 here:
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch7.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that's it. Only thing is that it seems to depend on the dimension of $\Omega$ and in $\mathbb{R}$, $H^1$ seems enough. We need $H^2$ in 2D though. At least I know the name of the property now :)